# Flex Cable Physics

Tags: modeling

how do I make the FLEX CABLE work like the real one? wherein it sticks to the connectors and moves like the actual FLEX CABLE on our PC? I cannot find a tutorial that allows me to accomplish this. In my mind, i'm thinking of STRING PHYSICS? But i'm just really not making it work.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One very easy way is to use a Hook Modifier and a Bezier curve with only two vertices (A bit limited I admit). The curve would stretch and might not keep its initial length (depending on the circumstances) though, but it does the trick in some cases.

First place a Bezier curve in the right location. Then select the thing you want it to connect to, and <kbd>Shift</kbd> select the Curve. Now with the two objects selected go into Edit Mode and select the "connecting" vertex and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd>. Choose Hook to Selected Object.

[image]

Now if you move or rotate the first selected object the curve will move with it.

[image]

Also any other bezier curve can be made to follow the cable curve. In the Properties window click the Object Data Properties tab. Then got to Geometry > Bevel > Object and select a bezier curve that you made in a shape of your liking.

[image]

And a very handy thing worth mentioning in this case is the vertex tilt. If you want to rotate a vertex along the length of the curve, select the vertex in Edit Mode and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd>

[image]